# Sql GROUP BY conflict with the arrays

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have this tables:

- Projectos: Pid, value, value, value...
- Sectores: ID, value, value, value...
- Projectos-Sectores: ProjectID(Pid), SectorID(ID)

I am doing this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Projectos` 
JOIN `Projectos-Sectores` ON `ProjectID` = `Pid` 
JOIN `Sectores` ON `SectorID` = `Sectores`.`ID`
GROUP BY `Pid`
```

All was correct at the first. Make the joins and group correctly. There aren't 'Pid' duplicate.

The problem came when only show the last coincidence in the table "Projectos-Sectores".

I want that return an array with all coincidence between "Projectos" & "Sectores". Without repeat 'Pid'.

Any idea?

Comment: Pls provide sample data and expected output! I do not really understand your question.

Comment: Does `Projectos` and `Sectores` have many to many relationship? Some sample data and expected output will be helpful for us to understand the question.

Comment: return this: **Array ( [0] => Array ( [Pid] => 1 [Pnombre] => Perversiones múltiples a lo loco [Pdescripcion] => Funkring Dungen Güergtain Cwoldimg [Pdueno] => 4 [PcantidadFin] => 455 [Pfinanciado] => 455 [PtiquetMinimo] => 34 [Ppais] => ES [Pimagen] => [ID] => 2 [CodeText] => APP))**     and should return    **Array ( [0] => Array ( [Pid] => 1 [Pnombre] => Perversiones múltiples a lo loco [Pdescripcion] => Funkring Dungen Güergtain Cwoldimg [Pdueno] => 4 [PcantidadFin] => 455 [Pfinanciado] => 455 [PtiquetMinimo] => 34 [Ppais] => ES [Pimagen] => [CodeText] => ([1] =>APP, [2] => ))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem came when i get the result and i want get the "sectores" linkeds to "Projectos". Only show the last coincidence in the table "Projectos-Sectores".

Yes, because you group by `Pid`.

> I want that return an array with all coincidence between "Projectos" & "Sectores". Without repeat 'Pid'.

You could for example order by `Pid` and then process all lines and group in the code which processes the rows, but you will get every row in the table and multiple `Pid` - transformation which transforms multiple lines into a different data structure which does not look like a relational database has to be done somewhere else but the database.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Projectos` 
JOIN `Projectos-Sectores` ON `ProjectID` = `Pid` 
JOIN `Sectores` ON `SectorID` = `Sectores`.`ID`
ORDER BY `Pid`
```